# AEM Servlet not getting executed

Tags: servlets, annotations, osgi, aem

I have a servlet with OSGI annotation like below

```
    @Component( immediate = true, service = Servlet.class, property = { "sling.servlet.extensions=json",
        "sling.servlet.paths=/example/search", "sling.servlet.methods=get" } )
    public class SearchSevrlet
        extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
      @Override
        protected void doGet( final SlingHttpServletRequest req, final SlingHttpServletResponse resp )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
      log.info("This is not getting called ");
    }
}
```

But When i try to hit the servlet with JQuery

```
$.get( "/example/search.json", function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

I am getting below information rather than servlet getting executed.

```
{"sling:resourceSuperType":"sling/bundle/resource","servletClass":"com.group.aem.example.servlet.SearchSevrlet","sling:resourceType":"/example/search.servlet","servletName":"com.group.aem.example.servlet.SearchSevrlet"}
```

Please let me know if i need to make any other configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info that you are getting is the answer of the [Default JSON Servlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html#default-json-rendering)

Please read this: [Servlets and Scripts](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)

You are registering the "SearchServlet" with the property "sling.servlet.paths". This property is defined as:

> **sling.servlet.paths**: A list of absolute paths under which the servlet is accessible as a Resource. The property value must either be a single String, an array of Strings...

That means that your servlet will be only triggered if you request the same exact path, in this case **"/example/search"**, like this:

```
GET /example/search
```

I would recommend you to use the properties "resourceTypes" and "selectors" in your Servlet rather than "paths". For example, a better configuration could be:

```
    property = { 
        "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=/example/search.servlet",
        "sling.servlet.selectors=searchselector",
        "sling.servlet.extensions=json",
        "sling.servlet.methods=GET" 
    }
```

With this config, your SearchServlet should be triggered with a **GET** request to a resource with **resourceType="/example/search.servlet"**, with the selector **"searchselector"** and the extension **"json"**. For example:

```
GET /corcoran/search.searchselector.json
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with yours.

To find out what is wrong, I checked "**Recent Requests**" page.
(at http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests.)

In my case, there was a log saying, "**Will not look for a servlet at **(my request path)** as it is not in the list of allowed paths**".

So I moved to "**Config Manager**" page(at http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr), and searched for "**Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler**".

It has a list named "**Execution Paths**", and I added my request path to the list.

After adding my path to the list, the problem is solved.